# glance error while uploading image to the Image Service

Tags: openstack

I am trying to upload the image to the Image Service using following command:

```
$ glance image-create --name "cirros-0.3.2-x86_64" --disk-format qcow2 \


 --container-format bare --is-public True --progress < cirros-0.3.2-x86_64-disk.img
```

But I am getting the following error:-

```
usage: glance [--version] [-d] [-v] [--get-schema] [--no-ssl-compression] [-f]
      [--os-image-url OS_IMAGE_URL]
      [--os-image-api-version OS_IMAGE_API_VERSION] [--insecure]
      [--os-cacert <ca-certificate>] [--os-cert <certificate>]
      [--os-key <key>] [--timeout <seconds>]
      [--os-auth-url OS_AUTH_URL] [--os-domain-id OS_DOMAIN_ID]
      [--os-domain-name OS_DOMAIN_NAME]
      [--os-project-id OS_PROJECT_ID]
      [--os-project-name OS_PROJECT_NAME]
      [--os-project-domain-id OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_ID]
      [--os-project-domain-name OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME]
      [--os-trust-id OS_TRUST_ID] [--os-user-id OS_USER_ID]
      [--os-username OS_USERNAME]
      [--os-user-domain-id OS_USER_DOMAIN_ID]
      [--os-user-domain-name OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME]
      [--os-password OS_PASSWORD] [--key-file OS_KEY]
      [--ca-file OS_CACERT] [--cert-file OS_CERT]
      [--os-tenant-id OS_TENANT_ID] [--os-tenant-name OS_TENANT_NAME]
      [--os-region-name OS_REGION_NAME]
      [--os-auth-token OS_AUTH_TOKEN]
      [--os-service-type OS_SERVICE_TYPE]
      [--os-endpoint-type OS_ENDPOINT_TYPE]
glance: error: unrecognized arguments: --is-public True
```

Please help me out with this error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the *--file* option. Also the option *--is-public* should be *--visibilty public* instead.

Try with the command from the official install guide:

```
glance image-create --name "cirros-0.3.2-x86_64" \
--file cirros-0.3.2-x86_64-disk.img \
--disk-format qcow2 --container-format bare \
--visibility public --progress
```

By the way... cirros has the version 0.3.4 available since long time, at:
    http://download.cirros-cloud.net/0.3.4/cirros-0.3.4-x86_64-disk.img

Comment: Thanks @Julen Larrucea for helping me out. But now I am getting the following error: Error finding address for http://controller:9292/versions: HTTPConnectionPool(host='controller', port=9292): Max retries exceeded with url: /versions (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f92d3c21990>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))

Comment: uff.. that starts getting more tricky... try "ping controller" and "service glance-api status"

Comment: I am able to ping controller and "service glance-api status"  returns glance-api stop/waiting

Comment: try "glance --debug image-list"

Comment: Same error.......Error finding address for controller:9292/versions: HTTPConnectionPool(host='controller', port=9292): Max retries exceeded with url: /versions (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f92d3c21990>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)) – uvrathore 27 mins ago

Comment: Wait, you said that the status of glance-api returned stop/waiting... it should say active (running)! Try to restart both glance-api and glance-registry. Are you sure the "connection" line is set properly on the config files?